# Extreme privacy setting in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity-dash, lenses, canonical, zeitgeist

Ubuntu is one of the greatest OS that I have ever used. However, I just wonder about the privacy because some of my activity will be sent to Cannonical server.

Are there any ways to prevent my data from sending to Cannonical server? Would you please help me to set?

I have played around with the "Privacy" setting but some options make me confuse

- In "File" tab, if I put one folder in "Dont record activity in the following folders", that means my activity in this folder is not logged but how about its child folder? Is it true that my activity in the sub folder will be logged?
- In "Applications" tab, I need to list down applications that I dont want to be logged. However, I have thousand of application so how can I let the OS not log any applications?

Regards,
Nam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your System Settings, and go to Privacy.

On the first tab of the Privacy section there is a switch to turn off next to "Include online search results" (or something similar).

This prevents anything you type into the Dash from being sent to Canonical's servers. (This disables the Amazon shopping lens and any lenses that are part of the Smart Scopes feature present in 13.10 when you upgrade.)

---

As a point of clarification: the portion you're talking about with the Record Activity settings is actually only a local feature. There is a program called Zeitgeist which keeps track of your most recently opened files and applications (Zeitgeist is also used by the GNOME desktop environment, actually). This is only used to prioritize results in the Dash; *none of that information is ever transmitted to Canonical or even leaves the computer.*

If that is still a privacy concern for you, by all means, still turn it off, but if you're only worried about the information that is leaving your computer, you just need to turn off the setting for including online results in the dash.

Personally, I find Zeitgeist to be helpful, so I leave it on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I uninstalled all lens except app lens in Unity and also removed the Zeitgeist. This post is useful http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2000108

Answer (score 3):

1. Search for System Settings in the Dash
2. Go to Privacy
3. At the bottom of the window you will see "Record Activity"
4. Set this setting to "OFF"

You can also turn Include online search results off from this same screen.

Comment: Your solution is ok but it is not the extreme way to protect privacy. I think we should remove the Zeitgeist and other unused lens(e.g. video, image, etc) except app lens.